# Hard drive capacity logs in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, logs, hard-disk

I am trying to figure out an event/log in linux preferably CentOS that can tell about the amount of capacity left for a specific hard drive or partition.So that I can set alerts on our monitoring system whenever the hard drive reaches 95% capacity it can generate an alert.

Thanks
F.

Comment: Great. Doesn't your monitoring system already provide a hook for this? Have you looked at `df`? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cat with many many skins to flay from it.  In no particular order, a few example solutions:

- Monit
- Nagios
- Cacti
- Splunk

Comment: Cacti and Monit are particularly easy to setup. +1

Comment: Hey there we are using SIEM solution's alert feature to trigger alert on certain events.So I am searching out an event or log in linux that can tell abut the amount of hard drive space left like we hvae an event in windows like srv2013 for hard drive space capacity.